# Can't View Express/React App in Heroku (concurrently not found)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, heroku, npm

I'm having trouble viewing my Node/Express + React project in Heroku. After successfully pushing my project to Heroku, I get a 404 error page when I try to view my app in heroku.

Heroku Logs shows that the `concurrently` package was not found

I was wondering if anyone can help me figure out why?
Everything works locally. No issues.
I haven't been able to find any solutions. I've tried this:
https://github.com/RickWong/react-isomorphic-starterkit/issues/12

I tried setting an environment variable in heroku with the following suggestion:

`heroku config:set NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false`

However, it did not work.

I also found this:

https://github.com/rickbergfalk/sqlpad/issues/359

I've attempted re-installing `concurrently` twice, in the server folder, as well as in root. But with each instance, I got the same error telling me that `concurrently` was not found.

Here is the Heroku log:

```
2019-01-05T04:44:42.843348+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2019-01-05T04:44:45.795355+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2019-01-05T04:44:45.817371+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2019-01-05T04:44:45.825275+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2019-01-05T04:44:45.691080+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-01-05T04:44:45.691107+00:00 app[web.1]: > hello_fullstack@1.0.0 start /app
2019-01-05T04:44:45.691110+00:00 app[web.1]: > concurrently -- kill-others "npm run server" "npm run client"
2019-01-05T04:44:45.691112+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-01-05T04:44:45.699841+00:00 app[web.1]: sh: 1: concurrently: not found
2019-01-05T04:44:45.704281+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! file sh
2019-01-05T04:44:45.704664+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2019-01-05T04:44:45.704985+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno ENOENT
2019-01-05T04:44:45.705300+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! syscall spawn
2019-01-05T04:44:45.706913+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! hello_fullstack@1.0.0 start: `concurrently -- kill-others "npm run server" "npm run client"`
2019-01-05T04:44:45.707140+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
2019-01-05T04:44:45.707475+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2019-01-05T04:44:45.707708+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the hello_fullstack@1.0.0 start script.
2019-01-05T04:44:45.708000+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2019-01-05T04:44:45.718125+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-01-05T04:44:45.718481+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2019-01-05T04:44:45.718674+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2019-01-05T04_44_45_709Z-debug.log
```

Any suggestions?

(Not sure this matters, but my dev environment is in ubuntu, which I'm running inside virtualbox; host os is Windows 8)

Comment: Do you have it listed as a dependency?

Comment: Hi Li357. Thank you so much for the lightning fast response. Yes, I do. I have it listed as a devDependency in root's package.json file.

Comment: dev (development) dependencies do not get installed in a production environment (in this case heroku...) In any case that would not be a proper way to deploy... All of your react has to be 'built 'and served as static assets...

Comment: @SakoBu yeah, I figured. After @Li357 asked me that question, it hit me that I installed concurrently under `devDependencies` and not `dependencies`. Now I feel silly. The "dev" part of devDependency seriously flew over my head there. I just uninstalled concurrently and re-installed it under dependencies. After pushing to heroku, I no longer get the 404 page, but instead a blank page with the text "Invalid Host header". Heroku logs now show "nodemon not found", which is now a new problem. I guess heroku sees concurrently now

Comment: so nodemon is under devDependencies or dependencies?

Comment: hey @Ammar, sorry for the late reply. nodemon is listed under "dependencies" in my root folder's package.json file, and so is concurrently. There are no longer any packages listed under "devDependencies" in that specific file

Comment: Forgot to say that after seeing the `nodemon not found` error, I ran npm install nodemon --save; afterwards, that error went away, but then I got a new one: `kill-others not found`

Comment: run `npm i` in the root directory. that should fix this. btw why have u kept nodemon inside dependencies

Comment: Hi @Ammar, running `npm i` did not fix the issue. Another new error came up: `Error: Cannot find module 'http-errors'`. It seems when I fix one thing, a new thing comes up. I'm going around in circles it seems

Comment: @Ammar it's listed under dependencies because a lot of the tutorials I looked at simply ran `npm install nodemon`, which is also the first command found here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon. I'm going to change it to devDependency though and see if that helps.

Answer (score 5):

I found a solution to my problem.

After struggling with it, I decided to just start over and build a sample react/express app, and see if I could deploy it to heroku. Upon successfully deploying, I compared the code from my sample app and my broken app. It then occurred to me that perhaps the issue was with the commands that I assigned to the `heroku-postbuild` script in the package.json file of my root folder.

Previously, I had this junk:

```
"heroku-postbuild": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client"
```

I changed that to this:

```
"heroku-postbuild": "cd client && npm install && npm run build"
```

And, like magic, it worked! I guess I wasn't "building" what I was supposed to build on the heroku side.