# MERN Heorku App Works Locally, Stores Data In MLAB but wont work using deployment link

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, heroku

I have this project working locally and it seems to be interacting with the mLab database on heroku when I save information through my localhost. However, when I use the heroku link, I get an application error which tells me to take a look at the logs. I posted a picture of the full log below.

Here is a link to the repo:https://github.com/TheGreekCuban/ButterflySocial
Heroku deployed link: https://butterflysocial.herokuapp.com/

I've tried deleting package-lock.json and node modules, I've made sure my config variables match up, I've read all similar material on the internet and still can't figure it out. I think it has to do with either:

1. The build process
2. The mlab connection

See error messages below.

I expect the app to run as it does locally. The error messages when I write heroku logs --tail are:

```
   2019-10-10T06:50:37.277769+00:00 app[web.1]: at Connection.emit (events.js:198:13)
2019-10-10T06:50:37.277771+00:00 app[web.1]: at processMessage (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connection.js:364:10)
2019-10-10T06:50:37.277773+00:00 app[web.1]: at Socket.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connection.js:533:15)
2019-10-10T06:50:37.277776+00:00 app[web.1]: at Socket.emit (events.js:198:13)
2019-10-10T06:50:37.277778+00:00 app[web.1]: at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:288:12)
2019-10-10T06:50:37.27778+00:00 app[web.1]: at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:269:11)
2019-10-10T06:50:37.277782+00:00 app[web.1]: at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:224:10)
2019-10-10T06:50:37.277784+00:00 app[web.1]: at TCP.onStreamRead [as onread] (internal/stream_base_commons.js:94:17)
2019-10-10T06:50:37.291411+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2019-10-10T06:50:37.292117+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
2019-10-10T06:50:37.293986+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! mern@1.0.0 start:prod: `node server.js`
2019-10-10T06:50:37.294229+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2019-10-10T06:50:37.294617+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2019-10-10T06:50:37.29488+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the mern@1.0.0 start:prod script.
2019-10-10T06:50:37.29508+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2019-10-10T06:50:37.302171+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-10-10T06:50:37.302456+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2019-10-10T06:50:37.30261+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2019-10-10T06_50_37_297Z-debug.log
2019-10-10T06:50:37.75424+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-10-10T06:50:37.754257+00:00 app[web.1]: > mern@1.0.0 start:dev /app
2019-10-10T06:50:37.754259+00:00 app[web.1]: > concurrently "nodemon --ignore 'client/*'" "npm run client"
2019-10-10T06:50:37.754261+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-10-10T06:50:37.760003+00:00 app[web.1]: sh: 1: concurrently: not found
2019-10-10T06:50:37.765837+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! file sh
2019-10-10T06:50:37.766059+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2019-10-10T06:50:37.766219+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno ENOENT
2019-10-10T06:50:37.766365+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! syscall spawn
2019-10-10T06:50:37.76744+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! mern@1.0.0 start:dev: `concurrently "nodemon --ignore 'client/*'" "npm run client"`
2019-10-10T06:50:37.767549+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
2019-10-10T06:50:37.767758+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2019-10-10T06:50:37.767881+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the mern@1.0.0 start:dev script.
2019-10-10T06:50:37.768053+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2019-10-10T06:50:37.772518+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-10-10T06:50:37.772726+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2019-10-10T06:50:37.772869+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2019-10-10T06_50_37_769Z-debug.log
2019-10-10T06:50:37.780063+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2019-10-10T06:50:37.780556+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
2019-10-10T06:50:37.78215+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! mern@1.0.0 start: `if-env NODE_ENV=production && npm run start:prod || npm run start:dev`
2019-10-10T06:50:37.782339+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2019-10-10T06:50:37.782696+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2019-10-10T06:50:37.782965+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the mern@1.0.0 start script.
2019-10-10T06:50:37.783129+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2019-10-10T06:50:37.788035+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-10-10T06:50:37.788187+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2019-10-10T06:50:37.78828+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2019-10-10T06_50_37_784Z-debug.log
2019-10-10T06:50:37.843017+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2019-10-10T06:50:37.880511+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2019-10-10T07:01:30.93415+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2019-10-10T07:01:47.992091+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2019-10-10T07:01:51.884742+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-10-10T07:01:51.884761+00:00 app[web.1]: > mern@1.0.0 start /app
2019-10-10T07:01:51.884764+00:00 app[web.1]: > if-env NODE_ENV=production && npm run start:prod || npm run start:dev
2019-10-10T07:01:51.884766+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-10-10T07:01:52.543917+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-10-10T07:01:52.543943+00:00 app[web.1]: > mern@1.0.0 start:prod /app
2019-10-10T07:01:52.543946+00:00 app[web.1]: > node server.js
2019-10-10T07:01:52.543948+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-10-10T07:01:54.038422+00:00 heroku[web.1]: source=web.1 dyno=heroku.149127838.c5e2572d-1b0e-42da-9a10-477a612609fa sample#memory_total=74.10MB sample#memory_rss=74.09MB sample#memory_cache=0.00MB sample#memory_swap=0.00MB sample#memory_pgpgin=19495pages sample#memory_pgpgout=3592pages sample#memory_quota=512.00MB
2019-10-10T07:01:54.299616+00:00 app[web.1]: mongodb://heroku_dvgm3n64:e7q2lkul6l3elf7qp3qbvu69vi@ds333248.mlab.com:33248/heroku_dvgm3n64
2019-10-10T07:01:54.333212+00:00 app[web.1]: does this do stuffs
2019-10-10T07:01:54.341108+00:00 app[web.1]: mongodb://useralex1:Emerson1*@ds333248.mlab.com:33248/heroku_dvgm3n64
2019-10-10T07:01:54.353677+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:42) DeprecationWarning: current Server Discovery and Monitoring engine is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new Server Discover and Monitoring engine, pass option { useUnifiedTopology: true } to the MongoClient constructor.
2019-10-10T07:01:54.354266+00:00 app[web.1]:   ==> API Server now listening on PORT 12283!
2019-10-10T07:01:54.421227+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/topologies/server.js:240
2019-10-10T07:01:54.42123+00:00 app[web.1]: throw err;
2019-10-10T07:01:54.421233+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2019-10-10T07:01:54.421235+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-10-10T07:01:54.421237+00:00 app[web.1]: MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [ds333248.mlab.com:33248] on first connect [MongoError: Authentication failed.]
2019-10-10T07:01:54.42124+00:00 app[web.1]: at Pool.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/topologies/server.js:431:11)
2019-10-10T07:01:54.421242+00:00 app[web.1]: at Pool.emit (events.js:198:13)
2019-10-10T07:01:54.421244+00:00 app[web.1]: at connect (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/pool.js:580:14)
2019-10-10T07:01:54.421246+00:00 app[web.1]: at callback (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:109:5)
2019-10-10T07:01:54.421248+00:00 app[web.1]: at provider.auth.err (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:352:21)
2019-10-10T07:01:54.42125+00:00 app[web.1]: at _authenticateSingleConnection (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/auth/auth_provider.js:66:11)
2019-10-10T07:01:54.421253+00:00 app[web.1]: at sendAuthCommand (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/auth/scram.js:177:16)
2019-10-10T07:01:54.421255+00:00 app[web.1]: at Connection.messageHandler (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:334:5)
2019-10-10T07:01:54.421257+00:00 app[web.1]: at Connection.emit (events.js:198:13)
2019-10-10T07:01:54.421259+00:00 app[web.1]: at processMessage (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connection.js:364:10)
2019-10-10T07:01:54.421261+00:00 app[web.1]: at Socket.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connection.js:533:15)
2019-10-10T07:01:54.421263+00:00 app[web.1]: at Socket.emit (events.js:198:13)
2019-10-10T07:01:54.421265+00:00 app[web.1]: at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:288:12)
2019-10-10T07:01:54.421267+00:00 app[web.1]: at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:269:11)
2019-10-10T07:01:54.421269+00:00 app[web.1]: at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:224:10)
2019-10-10T07:01:54.421271+00:00 app[web.1]: at TCP.onStreamRead [as onread] (internal/stream_base_commons.js:94:17)
2019-10-10T07:01:54.44114+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2019-10-10T07:01:54.442022+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
2019-10-10T07:01:54.444207+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! mern@1.0.0 start:prod: `node server.js`
2019-10-10T07:01:54.444479+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2019-10-10T07:01:54.444934+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2019-10-10T07:01:54.445255+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the mern@1.0.0 start:prod script.
2019-10-10T07:01:54.44552+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2019-10-10T07:01:54.458793+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-10-10T07:01:54.459372+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2019-10-10T07:01:54.459708+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2019-10-10T07_01_54_447Z-debug.log
2019-10-10T07:01:55.403829+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-10-10T07:01:55.403851+00:00 app[web.1]: > mern@1.0.0 start:dev /app
2019-10-10T07:01:55.403855+00:00 app[web.1]: > concurrently "nodemon --ignore 'client/*'" "npm run client"
2019-10-10T07:01:55.403857+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-10-10T07:01:55.465173+00:00 app[web.1]: sh: 1: concurrently: not found
2019-10-10T07:01:55.476951+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! file sh
2019-10-10T20:54:45.636326+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2019-10-10T20:54:59.872839+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2019-10-10T20:55:02.396371+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-10-10T20:55:02.39639+00:00 app[web.1]: > mern@1.0.0 start /app
2019-10-10T20:55:02.396393+00:00 app[web.1]: > if-env NODE_ENV=production && npm run start:prod || npm run start:dev
2019-10-10T20:55:02.396395+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-10-10T20:55:02.889922+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-10-10T20:55:02.889946+00:00 app[web.1]: > mern@1.0.0 start:prod /app
2019-10-10T20:55:02.889949+00:00 app[web.1]: > node server.js
2019-10-10T20:55:02.889952+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-10-10T20:55:03.004906+00:00 app[web.1]: internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:638
2019-10-10T20:55:03.004911+00:00 app[web.1]: throw err;
2019-10-10T20:55:03.004913+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2019-10-10T20:55:03.004915+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-10-10T20:55:03.00492+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module 'dotenv'
2019-10-10T20:55:03.004923+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
2019-10-10T20:55:03.004925+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
2019-10-10T20:55:03.004927+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
2019-10-10T20:55:03.004929+00:00 app[web.1]: at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
2019-10-10T20:55:03.004931+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/server.js:1:1)
2019-10-10T20:55:03.004933+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
2019-10-10T20:55:03.004935+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
2019-10-10T20:55:03.004937+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
2019-10-10T20:55:03.004938+00:00 app[web.1]: at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
2019-10-10T20:55:03.004943+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
2019-10-10T20:55:03.010806+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2019-10-10T20:55:03.011262+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
2019-10-10T20:55:03.012792+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! mern@1.0.0 start:prod: `node server.js`
2019-10-10T20:55:03.012894+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2019-10-10T20:55:03.013145+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2019-10-10T20:55:03.013407+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the mern@1.0.0 start:prod script.
2019-10-10T20:55:03.013617+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2019-10-10T20:55:03.023551+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-10-10T20:55:03.023712+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2019-10-10T20:55:03.023791+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2019-10-10T20_55_03_015Z-debug.log
2019-10-10T20:55:03.413352+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-10-10T20:55:03.413367+00:00 app[web.1]: > mern@1.0.0 start:dev /app
2019-10-10T20:55:03.41337+00:00 app[web.1]: > concurrently "nodemon --ignore 'client/*'" "npm run client"
2019-10-10T20:55:03.413372+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-10-10T20:55:03.418825+00:00 app[web.1]: sh: 1: concurrently: not found
2019-10-10T20:55:03.425842+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! file sh
2019-10-10T20:55:03.426173+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2019-10-10T20:55:03.426436+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno ENOENT
2019-10-10T20:55:03.426736+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! syscall spawn
2019-10-10T20:55:03.428257+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! mern@1.0.0 start:dev: `concurrently "nodemon --ignore 'client/*'" "npm run client"`
2019-10-10T20:55:03.428478+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
2019-10-10T20:55:03.428731+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2019-10-10T20:55:03.428905+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the mern@1.0.0 start:dev script.
2019-10-10T20:55:03.429153+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2019-10-10T20:55:03.437512+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-10-10T20:55:03.437701+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2019-10-10T20:55:03.437824+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2019-10-10T20_55_03_430Z-debug.log
2019-10-10T20:55:03.454807+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2019-10-10T20:55:03.455813+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
2019-10-10T20:55:03.457977+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! mern@1.0.0 start: `if-env NODE_ENV=production && npm run start:prod || npm run start:dev`
2019-10-10T20:55:03.458149+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2019-10-10T20:55:03.458451+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2019-10-10T20:55:03.45864+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the mern@1.0.0 start script.
2019-10-10T20:55:03.458836+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2019-10-10T20:55:03.477987+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-10-10T20:55:03.481718+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2019-10-10T20:55:03.481808+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2019-10-10T20_55_03_460Z-debug.log
2019-10-10T20:55:03.545013+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2019-10-10T20:55:03.590878+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2019-10-10T21:05:03.51307+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=HEAD path="/" host=butterflysocial.herokuapp.com request_id=fe75c157-e88e-4ca7-b764-32d93928a0e6 fwd="217.182.175.162" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-10-10T21:06:36.454645+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=butterflysocial.herokuapp.com request_id=58559acb-45a6-4d8e-b6e0-38e757eca259 fwd="199.185.67.21" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-10-10T21:06:36.326591+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=butterflysocial.herokuapp.com request_id=95fa4af1-c658-4bfc-a56a-2604aeda2e3b fwd="18.236.7.105" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
2019-10-10T21:06:39.322455+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=butterflysocial.herokuapp.com request_id=7b0ec73c-cfcf-428f-a2f2-a8067e621627 fwd="199.185.67.21" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-10-10T21:08:55.015408+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=butterflysocial.herokuapp.com request_id=f1f065b2-ee5c-4a6b-86e0-39a54898d9b4 fwd="89.247.167.20" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-10-10T21:08:55.447502+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=butterflysocial.herokuapp.com request_id=29cf9121-5e49-48c3-9404-9b61112d9d74 fwd="89.247.167.20" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Comment: It looks like you might be having two separate problems, an `[MongoError: Authentication failed.]` error and an error running the client app, also it may be running the dev app: `mern@1.0.0 start:dev /app`.

Double check the scripts, you should be able to see the logs during the build process (which should tell you when and if the client side was built successfully).

I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54058113/cant-view-express-react-app-in-heroku-concurrently-not-found

I vaguely remember having problems building with heroku even if the CLI says it's successful.

Comment: Hey, I just realized I didn't have the entire log in there. Just edited the code and added the rest. Not sure if that will give you any more clarity. Do you mean the build process when I do "git push heroku master"? I understand my ?s are probably very obvious but I am still only a couple months in with back-end so please bear with me.

Comment: OK @fvaldez421 - thank you! I am not sure what happened but it's now working. It was definitely something to do with my package.json scripts though. I ended up pulling an older copy from a previous commit and it worked. I probably ended up changing it one too many times and messed something up with the build.

Comment: Yes, when you `git push heroku master` it pushes the project to heroku and builds it on their end. The build logs should be available through the Dashboard -> Activity and you can click "View build log" on your most recent build to see the logs when the app was build and if there were any problems (unmet dependencies etc)