# Need help deploying full stack website to heroku: Error: There is likely additional logging output above

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, heroku, package-lock.json

I'm pretty new to fullstack development and have been trying to upload my site on heroku, I get this error message and I'm guessing it has something to do with my package-lock.json file in the root folder.

I have both front end and back end folders under one parent folder.
Here is the link to the small project if you can check it out: https://github.com/manuelmort/tft-project

I usually upload some small sites to gh-pages but since they dont support server side code I have to use heroku. It builds succesfully but the site never starts because of the error message below on heroku CLI

```
2022-01-04T16:23:14.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user manuelmort@gmail.com
2022-01-04T16:24:54.111750+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 8cc070c4 by user manuelmort@gmail.com
2022-01-04T16:24:54.111750+00:00 app[api]: Release v13 created by user manuelmort@gmail.com
2022-01-04T16:24:57.562224+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2022-01-04T16:25:02.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2022-01-04T16:25:04.610196+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2022-01-04T16:25:07.018112+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2022-01-04T16:25:07.018129+00:00 app[web.1]: > tft-project@1.0.0 start /app
2022-01-04T16:25:07.018130+00:00 app[web.1]: > concurrently "npm run backend" "npm run client"
2022-01-04T16:25:07.018130+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2022-01-04T16:25:07.022660+00:00 app[web.1]: sh: 1: concurrently: not found
2022-01-04T16:25:07.028749+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2022-01-04T16:25:07.028977+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! syscall spawn
2022-01-04T16:25:07.029095+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! file sh
2022-01-04T16:25:07.029286+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno ENOENT
2022-01-04T16:25:07.034404+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! tft-project@1.0.0 start: `concurrently "npm run backend""npm run client"`
2022-01-04T16:25:07.034446+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
2022-01-04T16:25:07.034492+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2022-01-04T16:25:07.034537+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the tft-project@1.0.0 start script.
2022-01-04T16:25:07.034580+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likelyadditional logging output above.
2022-01-04T16:25:07.040214+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2022-01-04T16:25:07.040320+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2022-01-04T16:25:07.040356+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2022-01-04T16_25_07_034Z-debug.log
2022-01-04T16:25:07.238236+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2022-01-04T16:25:07.301484+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2022-01-04T16:25:07.307500+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2022-01-04T16:25:15.521992+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2022-01-04T16:25:17.284061+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2022-01-04T16:25:17.284072+00:00 app[web.1]: > tft-project@1.0.0 start /app
2022-01-04T16:25:17.284073+00:00 app[web.1]: > concurrently "npm run backend" "npm run client"
2022-01-04T16:25:17.284073+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-01-04T16:25:17.298996+00:00 app[web.1]: sh: 1: concurrently: not found
2022-01-04T16:25:17.316611+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2022-01-04T16:25:17.317012+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! syscall spawn
2022-01-04T16:25:17.317189+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! file sh
2022-01-04T16:25:17.317369+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno ENOENT
2022-01-04T16:25:17.337279+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! tft-project@1.0.0 start: `concurrently "npm run backend""npm run client"`
2022-01-04T16:25:17.337583+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
2022-01-04T16:25:17.337807+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2022-01-04T16:25:17.337920+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the tft-project@1.0.0 start script.
2022-01-04T16:25:17.338041+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likelyadditional logging output above.
2022-01-04T16:25:17.347983+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-01-04T16:25:17.350592+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2022-01-04T16:25:17.350682+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2022-01-04T16_25_17_338Z-debug.log
2022-01-04T16:25:17.534240+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2022-01-04T16:25:17.755577+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Quote:  `This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above`.

Comment: There is no helpful information here.

Comment: Updated logs just now. Is there something else I should show to bring more information about my question, don't know if I'm showing you guys the right logs

Comment: `concurrently: not found`—it looks like `concurrently` is not available. Please show your `package.json`.

Comment: I provided the github link to the project

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/54058113/7099900

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I needed to have concurrently under dependencies and not devDependecies branch in my package.json file,
I don't get the error anymore

[image: package.json image]